# How do I backup a MongoDB data volume to host using docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to make it so every time my Docker application is run, a backup of all data in the `mongodb` container is backed up to a folder on the host computer. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker volumes for this. If you mounted a folder from your host onto the data directory of mongo (`/data/db`), all the databases, collections and documents you create in mongo will be stored on your host machine.

an bare minimum example docker-compose file for this would look like this

```
version: "3.5"

services:
  db:
    image: mongo
    container_name: db
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - ./mongo/data:/data/db
```

This will store the mongo data in the directory `mongo/data` in your current folder.